# java : why is it safe to modify a map's entry's value while we are iterating over it?

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, loops

Suppose a map contains integer keys, and a list of strings as its value. Then, I CAN'T  do this :

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    for (String string : entry.getValue()){
        if (string.startsWith("a")){
           entry.getValue().remove(string);
        }
    }
}
```

It throws `ConcurrentModificationException`. But if I do the following :

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    entry.setValue(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

This works perfectly. Aren't we modifying the underlying map even now ?

Comment: We are changing the value not adding or  removing any new entry so the key set remains the same.

Comment: BTW The first example will not throw a CME if you use `Iterator.remove()`

Comment: If I change any attribute of value Object . For example , if the value would have been List <Employee> and I change the name of the object of employee while iterating , why does it throw concurrent modification in that case  as we did not change the keys for that case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `Map`, only the way you're using the value list.  The following will fail with any `ArrayList`:

```
for (String string : list){
    if (string.startsWith("a")){
       list.remove(string);
    }
}
```

The reason for this is discussed in the Javadoc of `ArrayList`:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

(To put it another way: if you remove the element from the list, the iterator might not be pointing to the right index in the underlying array anymore.  So instead of allowing you to use a potentially corrupted iterator, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` as a courtesy to let you know that you need to redesign your program.)

A simple fix is to use

```
Iterator<String> itr = entry.getValue().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  if (itr.next().startsWith("a")) {
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the Javadoc for the entrySet() in HashMap.java and you will find out why!

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29):

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.
>
> Specified by: entrySet() in Map,
>
> Overrides: entrySet() in AbstractMap
>
> Returns: a set view of the mappings contained in this map